# Merge 2 PostgreSQL tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

```
table1 has attributes: Price, Name (IS)
table2 has attribute: Price, Name (IS)
```

I would like to update the `table1` Price entries with the price entries in `table2` when `table1.Name (IS)= table2.Name (IS)`

```
UPDATE table1
SET Price= table2.Price
FROM table2
WHERE table2.Name (IS)= table1.Name (IS)
```

> Column does not exist error

Comment: `WHERE table2.Name = table1.name`. You don't use the column dimensions when using the columns, only when creating the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you use special characters in column name need append column name between double-quotes, like bellow sample:

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET "Price" = table2."Price"
FROM table2
WHERE table2."Name (IS)" = table1."Name (IS)"
```

Comment: This correctly returns an UPDATE. However, after executing ``` SELECT * FROM table1;``` the new Prices have not been updated.